# Sort-of bug -- "in 0 seconds" instead of "0 seconds ago" or similar

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

After posting a comment, I see this:

[image: screenshot]

I think "in 0 seconds" is supposed to be "0 seconds ago" or something similar.  As-is, it doesn't make sense.

The immediate impression I get from that text is "this comment will be posted n seconds from now", or "this comment was posted -n seconds ago".  That might make sense if a delay was introduced for some reason, but not when the text shows up only after the comment is already posted.

If there has to be a special case for 0, why not make it show nothing?  I know I just posted the comment right now, no need to remind me :P

Comment: Interesting. (Also posting this comment to test.) At least on meta, I see "0 seconds ago": https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/6574/26709/qiyaindau64kxyj/upload.png. I wonder why there's a difference.

Comment: Could that be a browser-specific JavaScript bug?

Comment: Ah, I got it on Stack Overflow! http://i.imgur.com/RiPSi.png

Comment: @NReilingh: Not a JavaScript bug; the timestamps are retrieved directly from the server via AJAX call. See http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/posts/250/comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're going to say "just now" when things are at 0 secs.

Comment: Will this apply for negative seconds as well, when it doesn't make sense to have a future date?

Comment: Alrighty, [Jeff has fixed this or had this fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104921/bug-in-comment-timestamp/104939#104939).  Great!

Answer (score 2):

This is a curious instance that boils down to a timing issue, as it were. See, it's not 0 seconds ago because *this is in the future*. See [a much more egregious example of this on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73169/chat-box-on-parent-site-showing-conversation-from-the-future), where the chat sidebox informs users that someone is about to speak "in 2 seconds".

This instance arises from two points, basically. It's saying "in X seconds" instead of "X seconds ago" because the timestamp of the comment is apparently *after* the time that the page thinks you are on. And it's saying "0" because this happens to be small enough that it'll round to 0.

If you actually hit the exact time (at least on chat, I've seen such), it'll even say "just now" rather than "in 0 seconds" or "0 seconds ago".

Comment: Makes sense.  I assume this is probably useful for scheduled chat events, and such, but elsewhere it'll just cause confusion when it happens.  So I still view it as a bug.